# Converting a dropdown selection to a two digit number in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list which has items bound to it using sql datasource.

In the database i have the numeric values corresponding to each item.

Now there are many such dropdown list's and on selection of each item i want to form a 14 digit numeric code,which i need to use further for some more functionality.

How can i convert a selected item from a dropdownlist to a numeric digit??or how can i bind the items in the dropdownlist to a database having numeric value for each item?Please help.

E.g if i select `'WT'` from dropdown list the corresponding value for it in the database table is 39 so on form submit i want `'39'` to be formed in codebehind. likewise on selection of all items from different dropdown list the digit formed using codebehind should be `'15487523568955'`

Comment: nothing realy.i posted on stackoverflow as i wanted to move in right path from the begining.

Comment: Okay - can you show some sample input/output? Ie if the dropdown has a value "12313123", what 14-digit value should that produce? Also - why the JavaScript tag? Are you wanting to do this client-side or on form submit/selectedindexchanged?

Comment: No not random it should be like on selection of particular item,the same digit should be formed.

Comment: Do you have numeric value? If so it's simple matter of Int32.Parse(myDropDown.SelectedValue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok while binding your dropdown list to the sql datasource, you have to make sure that you bind

```
dropdownlist.DataSource = <GetSQLDataSource>();
dropdownlistDataTextField="<textvalue>"; 
dropdownlistDataValueField="<numericID>";
dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

Then, the Textvalue will be displayed in hte dropdown list and then you can access the corresponding .

Comment: You do this when you bind the data to the dropdownlist. You can do it on PageLoad.

Comment: How to define GetSQLDataSource??

Comment: I just mentioned <GetSQLDataSource>(). You will have to provide your datasource there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Explain your requirement in some more details and if possible also add the table fields which your displaying in the dropdown for more clearance.

If you have corresponding value for the each items in the dropdownlist then while bidning the dropdown bind both the corresponding value as well as well as items to the dropdown, so that u will get the selected item value.