# how to form a 3 digit code after a user enters some value in a textbox asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to first form a 3-digit code once a user enters some input in a textbox.

I have a database table that has the text value that is to be entered in a text box for these text values there is corresponding numeric value which ranges from 3-999.

suppose user enters 'asd' and corresponding value in the database table is 9 (**both 'asd' and '9'should be compared in the database table**) than i want a 3-digit number to be formed as '009'.

Similarly there are other controls such as DropDownList and other textboxes from which the user input must be read and converted to a particular numeric code and thus finally forming a 14 digit code.

How can i achieve this. I want to know the way i should proceed with this. I am very new to programming.

Comment: What happens if you want to insert 1000 records? Do you replace oldest ones?

Comment: I don't insert the records,the records are already there i just need to compare the user input to a corresponding value in database.

Comment: Hmmm seems very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181662/converting-a-dropdown-selection-to-a-two-digit-number-in-asp-net-c But this is a different user - did someone say "multiple accounts"?

Comment: @Sneha, well then all you need is to query the database given the user input which will give you the corresponding record and the 3 digit number. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @rpm1984 We both are working on same project but in different location.The other question i think is posted by my friend Ishan.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov its not a 3 digit it ranges from 3-999 so if i find 3 than i need to append 2 moredigits in front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the data table from the database and hold it into the data table
Then when the user write/select some values from the controls then call following method
and pass the DataTable and the user Input.
CompareItems Method will Return you the corresponding value of the UserInput.
Add your login for creating 3 digit number.

```
string spclDigit="";

private void CompareItems(DataTable dbTable, string value)
{        
    for (int j = 0; j < dbTable.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        //In the Below 
        if (dbTable.Rows[j]["ColumnName"].ToString() == value)
        {
            string newCorrspndngValue= dbTable.Rows[j]["ColumnName"].ToString();
            //Generate the 3 Digit No Here.
            spclDigit=spclDigit +//Add ur logic to Generate the 3 digit number
        }
    }
}
```